# Overload resolution in a strange method hierarchy

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance

I have an abstract base class `ServiceBase` with method `Execute`:

```
protected virtual void Execute(RestRequest request, Action<IRestResponse> callback)
{
    Client.ExecuteAsync(request, (response) => callback(response));
}
```

There is a class inherited from this abstract base class `DataServiceBase` which is also abstract and also have a method `Execute` but with little difference in parameters:

```
protected virtual void Execute(RestRequest request, Action<IRestResponse<Records>> callback)
{
    Client.ExecuteAsync<Records>(request, (response) => callback(response));
}
```

The last class which inherits from `DataServiceBase` is `GetDataByIdService`. This class also have a method `Execute` witch calls base `Execute`:

```
public void Execute(string peid, Action<IRestResponse> callback)
{
    var request = new RestRequest();
    request.AddUrlSegment(Peid, peid);
    Execute(request, callback);
}
```

The problem is as follows: 
`Execute(request, callback);` calls method `Execute` from `DataServiceBase` but I expect to call the correct method from `ServiceBase` class.

Usage example:

```
public void CallbackFunction(IRestResponse response)
{ ... }

var service  = new GetDataByIdService();
service.Execute("123456", CallbackFunction);
```

Comment: That's because your argument is an `Action<IRestResponse<Records>>`, not an `Action<IRestResponse> callback`. Your title talks about "overload/override" resolution but there's no overriding here, only overloading... and the ServiceBase.Execute method just isn't applicable. (Or if it is due to the interface hierarchy, the DataServiceBase method is more specific.)

Comment: The type of `callback` matches the signature of the `DataServiceBase` method.

Comment: Note that it would be easier to help you if you'd provide a short but complete example demonstrating the problem, along with the reason you *expect* it to call the method from ServiceBase.

Comment: @BartoszKP: Ah, that makes a bit more sense. Have just removed "override".